# Why use apply method

Tags: javascript

I read something about the global apply method but I don't understand why I should use the apply method?
Can you write to me some examples?

Comment: could you link to what you read..?

Comment: @ManseUK how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `.apply` when you want to call a function that takes a variable number of arguments and you don't know in advance how many you will be supplying.  So instead, you put those arguments into an array and call the function thus:

```
myfunc.apply(context, array);
```

which is equivalent to

```
myfunc(array[0], array[1], ...);
```

with `this` set equal to the `context` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at MDN there is a very good description (with examples) of apply():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply